# Convert a float/double to its IEEE754 representation

Tags: c++, ieee-754

I understand that we assign an `unsigned long long` because it contains the same number of bits as a `float`. But what exactly does `i` stand for?

My best interpretation is that we are trying to cast the double number to an `unsigned long long int` because they have the same number of bits. And it appears that the best way to do so is to dereference the pointer we have set up?

```cpp
void printDouble(double d) {
    unsigned long long int i = *(unsigned long long int *)&d;
    
    for (int j = 63; j >= 0; j--) {
        std::cout << ((i >> j) & 1);
    
        if (j == 63) std::cout << " ";
        else if (j == 52) std::cout << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is type punning and it's Undefined Behavior the way it's done here.

Comment: It works by violating the *strict aliasing rule*, but set that aside for a moment. You are looping 64 times (one for each bit in `i`) and you shift right by `j` bits and AND with `1` to isolate the bit of interest and output it. You check if `j` is `63` or `52` and output a space between the sign-bit and biased exponent and then again between the biased exponent and mantissa.

Comment: The code is UB as noted already. It would also work as `unsigned long long int &i = (unsigned long long int &)d;` (equally UB, but without an extra copy and maybe easier to read).

Comment: `float` is a single-precision type, using 32 bits. `double` is a double-precision type using 64 bits. `long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits.

Answer (score 7):

On most (but not all) platforms, `float` and `double` use IEEE 754 representation to approximate real valued numbers. For the meaning of the bits, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754. Briefly, in an IEEE-754 64-bit double, there is a sign bit, an 11-bit exponent, and a 52-bit significand (aka mantissa) to represent the real number in a form like

```
sign ⋅ 2^(exponent − 1023) ⋅ (1.0 + significand / 2^52)
```

There are special cases beyond this (infinities, [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), [subnormals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number), [signed zeros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero)), but that's the essential idea. If you are looking for a deeper reference, a great book is [Michael L. Overton, "Numerical Computing with IEEE Floating Point Arithmetic"](https://cs.nyu.edu/overton/book/index.html).

Beware that dereferencing `*(unsigned long long int *)&d` is undefined behavior, as others have commented. If you really want to get the bits of a double into a 64-bit int, a safe way to do that is through memcpy:

```
uint64_t bits;
std::memcpy(&bits, &d, sizeof(d));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since C++20 [std::bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) can be used:

```
std::uint64_t bits = std::bit_cast<std::uint64_t>(d);
```